# How do I pass origin and destination co-ordinates to the Google Maps directions API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, object

I'm using the google maps api for directions but i'm having problems when i try to send the origin and destination as coordinates.it says in the documentation that i can do that

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/#RequestParameters

but i am not sure of the format because it keeps giving me errors

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid value for property <origin>: [object Object]
```

i tried like so:

```
 {"Ja":27,"Ka":45}
 {latitude:27,longitude:45}
```

And all of the possible combinations above but still gives error which is weird because the objects are identical with the ones i should be sending.

Comment: If you pass coordinates, ensure that no space exists between the latitude and longitude values. What does that mean ?

Comment: Can you put some code? JSfiddle.net is a good place to share your example...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just provide the latidute/longitude separated by a comma as textual value:

`http://maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=27.111,45.222&destination=28.333,46.444&sensor=false`

Comment: Your request is also not working    {
   "routes" : [],
   "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
}

Comment: The request is working, but there is no route available for those coordinates(it's starting somewhere in a arabian desert).

Comment: that should work
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=43.6533103,-79.3827675&destination=45.5085712,-73.5537674&sensor=false

Comment: by default it will use "driving" as the travel method, which will only give a result if there is a way to drive from A to B. From the arabian desert, you should try "walking".

Comment: What does the sensor variable do?

Answer (score 0):

Use Google distancematrix API:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=-0.6566588,35.0881299&destinations=-0.6433411,35.094122&mode=driving
```